# Mounting with fstab - error 13 (access denied)

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

I have one server that is mounting with fstab using a credentials file.  The credentials file (.Smbcredentials) code is :

```
username=my_windows_login
password=my_password
domain=my_domain
```

My code in fstab is:

```
//myshare/myfolder /mnt/backup cifs credentials=/home/mydirectory/.Smbcredentials
```

This works perfectly.  However, when trying to duplicate this on another server (same version) I get

```
mount error 13 = Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g.man mount.cifs)
```

I'm running as root, all the folder permissions are identical.....everything is identical.  Yet I get error 13 on the new server only.  What could be wrong?

Comment: have you checked /var/log/ for anything that may hint at what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'users' into the fstab options:

```
//myshare/myfolder /mnt/backup cifs users,credentials=/home/mydirectory/.Smbcredentials 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Ubuntu wiki page, try adding a few of the missing params and make sure your cred file is 600:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

```
chmod 600 ~/.Smbcredentials
```

fstab line:

```
//myshare/myfolder /mnt/backup cifs credentials=/home/mydirectory/.Smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

EDIT:

Have you tried outside of fstab to get this mounted? Maybe using the mount command would give you some more usable output

```
mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD //myshare/myfolder /mnt/backup
```

Comment: I have ensured that the file is chmod 600 and added the parameters, but I still get error 13.

Comment: added something to try

Comment: Oddly enough, mounting outside of fstab works.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using `sudo` to mount?

I was under the impression that `/mnt/` was not writable by regular users.

ie: `sudo mount /mnt/backup`

Also, make sure that your fstab entry includes `0 0` at the end.

Comment: you are correct that normal users cannot just mount devices. however i think he is trying this in fstab which should be used under the root account at boot.

Comment: Correct, I am doing this under root.  I have also tried adding 00 to the fstab but it did not fix it.

Comment: the space in between the zeros is very important, btw.

Comment: I assume that there is a reason why you don't want your plaintext password in the fstab file. if not, you can replace `credentials=/home/mydirectory/.Smbcredentials` with `username=user,password=password,domain=domain`